# why is the cabal sandbox inited after installing yesod-bin?

Tags: cabal, yesod

On the Yesod homepage (http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) the following installation sequence is suggested:

```
wget http://www.stackage.org/lts/cabal.config
cabal update                       # download package list
cabal install alex happy yesod-bin # install build tools
yesod init --bare                  # answer questions as prompted
cabal sandbox init                 # set up a sandbox
cabal install --run-tests          # install libraries
yesod devel                        # launch devel server
```

My question is:
why is "cabal sandbox init" not directly after "cabal update"?

In the suggested way alex happy yesod-bin are all installed in the global space instead of inside the sandbox.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it generally confuses people when they can't run `yesod` directly; installing the executables into `~/.cabal/bin` means that the user can always access them. It *does* leak some information outside of the sandbox, but it's typically the right trade-off to take.

Comment: To add to this, alex and happy are build tools that several packages use, but unfortunately Cabal [won't install build tools automatically](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/220). You probably want them in your global package database to prevent errors installing other packages

Comment: seems like someone had a similar problem and changed the workflow a bit to get it all into a sandbox: https://gist.github.com/krdlab/712defa9304069af583d